# Understanding Fredholm integral equation and to proof it is a contraction on C[a,b]

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

This is my first time to see a Fredholm integral equation for a function $f(x)$. The definition is the following, $$\psi (f(x))=\lambda\int^{b}_{a}K(x,y)f(y)dy+\phi(x)$$is a Fredholm integral equation for $f(x)$. The functions $K$ and $\phi$ are continuous and $\lambda$ is a positive constant. I wonder what does this mean? What does it do to $f(x)$? The thing I knew is that it send countinuous function on $[a,b$ to continusous function on $[a,b]$. I want to show that $\psi (f(x))=\lambda\int^{b}_{a}K(x,y)f(y)dy+\phi(x)$ has only one unique solution if $$|K(x,y)|<=M$$, M is constant for all $(x,y)\in[a,b]x[a,b]$ and $\lambda M |b-a|<1$. I know that $C([a,b])$ is a complete space. I feel like I shall proof that $\psi (f)$ is a contraction mapping and then apply for contraction mapping principle, since $C([a,b])$ is complete. But I have difficult time to understand $\psi (f)$ and to see what is a contraction on $C([a,b])$ look like. Could anyone give me some suggestions?
Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The Fredholm integral equation is
$$
f(x)=\lambda\int^{b}_{a}K(x,y)\,f(y)\,dy+\phi(x).
$$
$\psi$ is a linear operator from $C([a,b])$ into itself defined by
$$
(\psi f)(x)=\lambda\int^{b}_{a}K(x,y)\,f(y)\,dy+\phi(x).
$$
The equation can then be writtenn as $\psi f=f$. To see that $\psi$ is a contraction we have to see that if $f,g\in C([a,b])$ then
$$
\|\psi f-\psi g\|\le c\,\|f-g\|,
$$
where $\|f\|=\sup_{a\le x\le b}|f(x)|$ is the uniform norm and $0\le c<1$. We have
$$
1(\psi f)(x)-\psi g)(x)|\le|\lambda|\int_a^b|K(x,y)|\,|f(y)-g(y)|\,dy\le|\lambda|\,M(b-a)\,\|f-g\|.
$$
Taking the sup in $x$ we get
$$
\|\psi f-\psi g\|\le|\lambda|\,M(b-a)\,\|f-g\|.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. May I ask a additional question? How about if I remove the condition λM|b−a|<1 and $\lambda >0$, while keep all the rest the same? like a Volterra integral equation? $$f(x)=\lambda\int^{x}_{a}K(x,y)\,f(y)\,dy+\phi(x).$$. will it still be contraction?

Comment: The sign of $\lambda$ does not matter, but you cannot get rid of the condition $|\lambda|\,M(b-a)<1$.